# What can could cause a 'doubled' stack like this?

Tags: c++, sas, crash, odbc

A user has reported a crash with an ODBC driver built with our SDK, and provided two core dumps. I'll provide the stack traces below:

First crash:

```
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!_wassert(const wchar_t * expr, const wchar_t * filename, unsigned int lineno) Line 369 C
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::ODBC::ODBCTaskContainer::SetTask(Simba::ODBC::IODBCTask * in_taskPointer) Line 61   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::ODBC::Statement::~Statement() Line 413  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::ODBC::Statement::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int) C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!`anonymous namespace'::DeleteAndRemove<std::vector<Simba::ODBC::Statement * __ptr64,std::allocator<Simba::ODBC::Statement * __ptr64> > >(std::vector<Simba::ODBC::Statement *,std::allocator<Simba::ODBC::Statement *> > & in_vector, std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Simba::ODBC::Statement *> > > in_toDeleteAndRemove) Line 429   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::ODBC::Connection::DeleteStatement(Simba::ODBC::Statement * in_statement) Line 846   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::ODBC::ConnectionState::SQLFreeHandle(Simba::ODBC::Connection * in_connection, short HandleType, void * Handle) Line 179 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::ODBC::Connection::SQLFreeHandle(short HandleType, void * Handle) Line 1592  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!SQLFreeHandle::__l346::<lambda>() Line 1931    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!std::_Callable_obj<short <lambda>(void),0>::_ApplyX<short>() Line 284  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!std::_Func_impl<std::_Callable_obj<short <lambda>(void),0>,std::allocator<std::_Func_class<short> >,short>::_Do_call() Line 229    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!std::_Func_class<short>::operator()() Line 316 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!_default_sen_odbc_api_function_wrapper_(std::function<short __cdecl(void)> & apiFunction) Line 773 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!SQLFreeHandle(short HandleType, void * Handle) Line 2014   C++
    MPAPlugin.dll!SQLFreeHandle(short HandleType, void * Handle) Line 1786  C++
    odbc32.dll!FreeStmt()  Unknown
    odbc32.dll!SQLFreeHandle()  Unknown
    sasodb.dll!00000000064d7187()   Unknown
    sasodb.dll!00000000064c1b26()   Unknown
    sasioodb.dll!000000000638d6a6() Unknown
    sasxdbi.dll!0000000006456fe3()  Unknown
    sasxdbi.dll!0000000006417fdf()  Unknown
    sasyh.dll!00000000053cec60()    Unknown
    sasyh.dll!00000000053c157a()    Unknown
    sasxkern.dll!0000000005155a2c() Unknown
    sashost.dll!000000000383e9b2()  Unknown
    sashost.dll!000000000383b877()  Unknown
    sashost.dll!000000000383b375()  Unknown
    sashost.dll!000000000383d962()  Unknown
    sashost.dll!000000000384081f()  Unknown
    sashost.dll!000000000383c4e3()  Unknown
    sashost.dll!00000000038322c4()  Unknown
    sashost.dll!000000000384628f()  Unknown
    sashost.dll!0000000003849d10()  Unknown
    sashost.dll!000000000383d509()  Unknown
    sashost.dll!00000000038506f0()  Unknown
    sashost.dll!000000000384f649()  Unknown
    0000000004846610()  Unknown
    fe48daea1d7f4cf6()  Unknown
    cccccccccccccccc()  Unknown
    000000000d3683d0()  Unknown
>   RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::Support::AutoPtr<sbicu_58::GregorianCalendar,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<sbicu_58::GregorianCalendar> >::operator->() Line 142   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!`anonymous namespace'::CreateEmptyCalendar(Simba::Support::ILogger * in_logger) Line 118   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::Support::TimestampTzConverter::TimestampTzConverter(const Simba::Support::simba_wstring & in_format, Simba::Support::ILogger * in_logger) Line 395  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::RestSQL::RSAbstractTable::RSAbstractTable(Simba::Support::ILogger * in_log, Simba::RestSQL::Settings & in_settings, Simba::RestSQL::RSConnection & in_connection, Simba::RestSQL::RestAPI & in_api, const Simba::RestSQL::_TableInfo & in_tableInfo, Simba::Support::IWarningListener * in_errorsListener, Simba::DriverSupport::HandlePool<void *,Simba::WebServiceSupport::CurlHandleManager,std::vector<void *,std::allocator<void *> > > & in_curlPool, Simba::RestSQL::MPAWrapper & in_mpa, Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::RestSQL::EndpointParameterInfo,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::RestSQL::EndpointParameterInfo> > in_executionEndpoint) Line 538   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::RestSQL::RSTableT<Simba::RestSQL::RSJsonTable>::RSTableT<Simba::RestSQL::RSJsonTable>(Simba::Support::ILogger * in_log, Simba::RestSQL::Settings & in_settings, Simba::RestSQL::RSConnection & in_connection, Simba::RestSQL::RestAPI & in_api, const Simba::RestSQL::_TableInfo & in_tableInfo, Simba::Support::IWarningListener * in_errorsListener, Simba::DriverSupport::HandlePool<void *,Simba::WebServiceSupport::CurlHandleManager,std::vector<void *,std::allocator<void *> > > & in_curlPool, Simba::RestSQL::MPAWrapper & in_mpa, Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::RestSQL::EndpointParameterInfo,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::RestSQL::EndpointParameterInfo> > in_executionEndpoint) Line 807   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::RestSQL::RSJsonTable::RSJsonTable(Simba::Support::ILogger * in_log, Simba::RestSQL::Settings & in_settings, Simba::RestSQL::RSConnection & in_connection, Simba::RestSQL::RestAPI & in_api, const Simba::RestSQL::_TableInfo & in_tableInfo, Simba::Support::IWarningListener * in_errorsListener, Simba::DriverSupport::HandlePool<void *,Simba::WebServiceSupport::CurlHandleManager,std::vector<void *,std::allocator<void *> > > & in_curlPool, Simba::RestSQL::MPAWrapper & in_mpa, Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::RestSQL::EndpointParameterInfo,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::RestSQL::EndpointParameterInfo> > in_executionEndpoint) Line 54    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::RestSQL::RSTableFactory::CreateRSTable(Simba::Support::ILogger * in_log, Simba::RestSQL::Settings & in_settings, Simba::RestSQL::RSConnection * in_connection, Simba::RestSQL::RestAPI & in_api, const Simba::RestSQL::_TableInfo & in_tableInfo, Simba::Support::IWarningListener * in_errorsListener, Simba::DriverSupport::HandlePool<void *,Simba::WebServiceSupport::CurlHandleManager,std::vector<void *,std::allocator<void *> > > & in_curlPool, Simba::RestSQL::MPAWrapper & in_mpa, Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::RestSQL::EndpointParameterInfo,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::RestSQL::EndpointParameterInfo> > in_executionEndpoint) Line 72   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::RestSQL::RSDataEngine::OpenTable(const Simba::Support::simba_wstring & in_catalogName, const Simba::Support::simba_wstring & in_schemaName, const Simba::Support::simba_wstring & in_tableName, Simba::SQLEngine::DSIExtTableOpenType in_openType) Line 200 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::ViewSupport::ViewManagedDataEngine<Simba::RestSQL::RSDataEngine>::OpenTable(const Simba::Support::simba_wstring & in_catalogName, const Simba::Support::simba_wstring & in_schemaName, const Simba::Support::simba_wstring & in_tableName, Simba::SQLEngine::DSIExtTableOpenType in_openType) Line 276  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AETableNameBuilder::VisitNonTerminalParseNode(Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode * in_node) Line 70    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode::AcceptVisitor(Simba::SQLEngine::IParseTreeVisitor & in_visitor) Line 486 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEBuilderBaseT<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr,Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr> > >::Build(Simba::SQLEngine::PSParseNode * in_node) Line 70  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AETableRefBuilder::VisitNonTerminalParseNode(Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode * in_node) Line 77 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode::AcceptVisitor(Simba::SQLEngine::IParseTreeVisitor & in_visitor) Line 486 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEBuilderBaseT<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr,Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr> > >::Build(Simba::SQLEngine::PSParseNode * in_node) Line 70  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AETableRefListBuilder::VisitNonTerminalParseNode(Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode * in_node) Line 48 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode::AcceptVisitor(Simba::SQLEngine::IParseTreeVisitor & in_visitor) Line 486 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEBuilderBaseT<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr,Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr> > >::Build(Simba::SQLEngine::PSParseNode * in_node) Line 70  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEQuerySpecBuilder::VisitNonTerminalParseNode(Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode * in_node) Line 85    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode::AcceptVisitor(Simba::SQLEngine::IParseTreeVisitor & in_visitor) Line 486 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEBuilderBaseT<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr,Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr> > >::Build(Simba::SQLEngine::PSParseNode * in_node) Line 70  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExprBuilder::BuildSelectStatement(Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode * in_node) Line 132   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExprBuilder::VisitNonTerminalParseNode(Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode * in_node) Line 65   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode::AcceptVisitor(Simba::SQLEngine::IParseTreeVisitor & in_visitor) Line 486 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEBuilderBaseT<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr,Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr> > >::Build(Simba::SQLEngine::PSParseNode * in_node) Line 70  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEQueryBuilder::VisitNonTerminalParseNode(Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode * in_node) Line 66    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode::AcceptVisitor(Simba::SQLEngine::IParseTreeVisitor & in_visitor) Line 486 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEBuilderBaseT<Simba::SQLEngine::AEStatement,Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::SQLEngine::AEStatement,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::SQLEngine::AEStatement> > >::Build(Simba::SQLEngine::PSParseNode * in_node) Line 70 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEStatementBuilder::BuildQuery(Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode * in_node) Line 146  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEStatementBuilder::VisitNonTerminalParseNode(Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode * in_node) Line 60    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode::AcceptVisitor(Simba::SQLEngine::IParseTreeVisitor & in_visitor) Line 486 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEBuilderBaseT<Simba::SQLEngine::AEStatement,Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::SQLEngine::AEStatement,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::SQLEngine::AEStatement> > >::Build(Simba::SQLEngine::PSParseNode * in_node) Line 70 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEAetBuilder::Build(Simba::SQLEngine::PSParseNode * in_node, Simba::SQLEngine::DSIExtSqlDataEngine * in_dataEngine) Line 22  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::DSIExtSqlDataEngine::Prepare(const Simba::Support::simba_wstring & in_sqlStatement) Line 170 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::ODBC::StatementState::InternalPrepare(wchar_t * in_sqlText, int in_textLength, bool in_isDirectExecute) Line 1492   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::ODBC::StatementState::DoPrepare(wchar_t * in_sqlText, int in_textLength, bool in_isDirectExecute) Line 877  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::ODBC::StatementState::SQLPrepareW(wchar_t * StatementText, long TextLength) Line 742    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::ODBC::StatementState1::SQLPrepareW(wchar_t * StatementText, long TextLength) Line 43    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::ODBC::Statement::SQLPrepareW(wchar_t * StatementText, long TextLength) Line 1253    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::ODBC::SQLPrepareTask<1>::DoSynchronously(Simba::ODBC::Statement & in_stmt, const Simba::ODBC::SQLPrepareTask<1>::TaskParameters & in_params) Line 211   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!DoTask<Simba::ODBC::SQLPrepareTask<1> >(const char * in_functionName, void * in_handle, Simba::ODBC::SQLPrepareTask<1>::TaskParameters & in_parameters) Line 685   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!SQLPrepareW::__l3::<lambda>() Line 4061    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!std::_Callable_obj<short <lambda>(void),0>::_ApplyX<short>() Line 284  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!std::_Func_impl<std::_Callable_obj<short <lambda>(void),0>,std::allocator<std::_Func_class<short> >,short>::_Do_call() Line 229    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!std::_Func_class<short>::operator()() Line 316 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!_default_sen_odbc_api_function_wrapper_(std::function<short __cdecl(void)> & apiFunction) Line 773 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!SQLPrepareW(void * StatementHandle, wchar_t * StatementText, long TextLength) Line 4061    C++
    MPAPlugin.dll!SQLPrepareW(void * StatementHandle, wchar_t * StatementText, long TextLength) Line 2251   C++
    odbc32.dll!SQLPrepareCover()    Unknown
    odbc32.dll!SQLPrepare()    Unknown
    sasodb.dll!00000000064d7ab9()   Unknown
    sasodb.dll!00000000064c3e06()   Unknown
    sasioodb.dll!00000000063c17a4() Unknown
    sasxdbi.dll!000000000644e0fa()  Unknown
    sasxdbi.dll!0000000006415abb()  Unknown
    sasyoio.dll!000000000bdaad5f()  Unknown
    sasyoio.dll!000000000bda7597()  Unknown
    sassqlp.dll!000000000ba4a787()  Unknown
    sassqlp.dll!000000000ba49d8e()  Unknown
    sassqlp.dll!000000000ba36853()  Unknown
    sassqlp.dll!000000000ba30cd2()  Unknown
    sassqx.dll!000000000b8a54b3()   Unknown
    sassqx.dll!000000000b8a4c0e()   Unknown
    sassql.dll!00000000092c147c()   Unknown
    sashost.dll!000000000384a366()  Unknown
    sashost.dll!0000000003850574()  Unknown
    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart() Unknown
```

The second crash:

```
>   kernel32.dll!IsBadReadPtr() Unknown
    tkmk.dll!0000000010051baa() Unknown
    tkmk.dll!000000001005383d() Unknown
    tkmk.dll!0000000010053587() Unknown
    tkmk.dll!0000000010054f63() Unknown
    tkmk.dll!0000000010055713() Unknown
    tkmk.dll!0000000010056894() Unknown
    tkmk.dll!0000000010056715() Unknown
    tkmk.dll!000000001005692b() Unknown
    tkmk.dll!00000000100566f9() Unknown
    tkmk.dll!000000001004aaaa() Unknown
    sashost.dll!0000000003761589()  Unknown
    sashost.dll!00000000037521c4()  Unknown
    sashost.dll!000000000376628f()  Unknown
    sashost.dll!0000000003769d10()  Unknown
    sashost.dll!000000000375d509()  Unknown
    sashost.dll!00000000037706f0()  Unknown
    sashost.dll!000000000376f649()  Unknown
    0000000004844e40()  Unknown
    fe48daea1d7f4cf6()  Unknown
    cccccccccccccccc()  Unknown
    000000000cbd83d0()  Unknown
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::Support::AutoPtr<sbicu_58::GregorianCalendar,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<sbicu_58::GregorianCalendar> >::operator->() Line 142   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!`anonymous namespace'::CreateEmptyCalendar(Simba::Support::ILogger * in_logger) Line 118   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::Support::TimestampTzConverter::TimestampTzConverter(const Simba::Support::simba_wstring & in_format, Simba::Support::ILogger * in_logger) Line 395  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::RestSQL::RSAbstractTable::RSAbstractTable(Simba::Support::ILogger * in_log, Simba::RestSQL::Settings & in_settings, Simba::RestSQL::RSConnection & in_connection, Simba::RestSQL::RestAPI & in_api, const Simba::RestSQL::_TableInfo & in_tableInfo, Simba::Support::IWarningListener * in_errorsListener, Simba::DriverSupport::HandlePool<void *,Simba::WebServiceSupport::CurlHandleManager,std::vector<void *,std::allocator<void *> > > & in_curlPool, Simba::RestSQL::MPAWrapper & in_mpa, Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::RestSQL::EndpointParameterInfo,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::RestSQL::EndpointParameterInfo> > in_executionEndpoint) Line 538   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::RestSQL::RSTableT<Simba::RestSQL::RSJsonTable>::RSTableT<Simba::RestSQL::RSJsonTable>(Simba::Support::ILogger * in_log, Simba::RestSQL::Settings & in_settings, Simba::RestSQL::RSConnection & in_connection, Simba::RestSQL::RestAPI & in_api, const Simba::RestSQL::_TableInfo & in_tableInfo, Simba::Support::IWarningListener * in_errorsListener, Simba::DriverSupport::HandlePool<void *,Simba::WebServiceSupport::CurlHandleManager,std::vector<void *,std::allocator<void *> > > & in_curlPool, Simba::RestSQL::MPAWrapper & in_mpa, Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::RestSQL::EndpointParameterInfo,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::RestSQL::EndpointParameterInfo> > in_executionEndpoint) Line 807   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::RestSQL::RSJsonTable::RSJsonTable(Simba::Support::ILogger * in_log, Simba::RestSQL::Settings & in_settings, Simba::RestSQL::RSConnection & in_connection, Simba::RestSQL::RestAPI & in_api, const Simba::RestSQL::_TableInfo & in_tableInfo, Simba::Support::IWarningListener * in_errorsListener, Simba::DriverSupport::HandlePool<void *,Simba::WebServiceSupport::CurlHandleManager,std::vector<void *,std::allocator<void *> > > & in_curlPool, Simba::RestSQL::MPAWrapper & in_mpa, Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::RestSQL::EndpointParameterInfo,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::RestSQL::EndpointParameterInfo> > in_executionEndpoint) Line 54    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::RestSQL::RSTableFactory::CreateRSTable(Simba::Support::ILogger * in_log, Simba::RestSQL::Settings & in_settings, Simba::RestSQL::RSConnection * in_connection, Simba::RestSQL::RestAPI & in_api, const Simba::RestSQL::_TableInfo & in_tableInfo, Simba::Support::IWarningListener * in_errorsListener, Simba::DriverSupport::HandlePool<void *,Simba::WebServiceSupport::CurlHandleManager,std::vector<void *,std::allocator<void *> > > & in_curlPool, Simba::RestSQL::MPAWrapper & in_mpa, Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::RestSQL::EndpointParameterInfo,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::RestSQL::EndpointParameterInfo> > in_executionEndpoint) Line 72   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::RestSQL::RSDataEngine::OpenTable(const Simba::Support::simba_wstring & in_catalogName, const Simba::Support::simba_wstring & in_schemaName, const Simba::Support::simba_wstring & in_tableName, Simba::SQLEngine::DSIExtTableOpenType in_openType) Line 200 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::ViewSupport::ViewManagedDataEngine<Simba::RestSQL::RSDataEngine>::OpenTable(const Simba::Support::simba_wstring & in_catalogName, const Simba::Support::simba_wstring & in_schemaName, const Simba::Support::simba_wstring & in_tableName, Simba::SQLEngine::DSIExtTableOpenType in_openType) Line 276  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AETableNameBuilder::VisitNonTerminalParseNode(Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode * in_node) Line 70    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode::AcceptVisitor(Simba::SQLEngine::IParseTreeVisitor & in_visitor) Line 486 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEBuilderBaseT<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr,Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr> > >::Build(Simba::SQLEngine::PSParseNode * in_node) Line 70  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AETableRefBuilder::VisitNonTerminalParseNode(Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode * in_node) Line 77 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode::AcceptVisitor(Simba::SQLEngine::IParseTreeVisitor & in_visitor) Line 486 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEBuilderBaseT<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr,Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr> > >::Build(Simba::SQLEngine::PSParseNode * in_node) Line 70  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AETableRefListBuilder::VisitNonTerminalParseNode(Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode * in_node) Line 48 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode::AcceptVisitor(Simba::SQLEngine::IParseTreeVisitor & in_visitor) Line 486 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEBuilderBaseT<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr,Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr> > >::Build(Simba::SQLEngine::PSParseNode * in_node) Line 70  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEQuerySpecBuilder::VisitNonTerminalParseNode(Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode * in_node) Line 85    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode::AcceptVisitor(Simba::SQLEngine::IParseTreeVisitor & in_visitor) Line 486 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEBuilderBaseT<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr,Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr> > >::Build(Simba::SQLEngine::PSParseNode * in_node) Line 70  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExprBuilder::BuildSelectStatement(Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode * in_node) Line 132   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExprBuilder::VisitNonTerminalParseNode(Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode * in_node) Line 65   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode::AcceptVisitor(Simba::SQLEngine::IParseTreeVisitor & in_visitor) Line 486 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEBuilderBaseT<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr,Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::SQLEngine::AERelationalExpr> > >::Build(Simba::SQLEngine::PSParseNode * in_node) Line 70  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEQueryBuilder::VisitNonTerminalParseNode(Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode * in_node) Line 66    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode::AcceptVisitor(Simba::SQLEngine::IParseTreeVisitor & in_visitor) Line 486 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEBuilderBaseT<Simba::SQLEngine::AEStatement,Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::SQLEngine::AEStatement,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::SQLEngine::AEStatement> > >::Build(Simba::SQLEngine::PSParseNode * in_node) Line 70 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEStatementBuilder::BuildQuery(Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode * in_node) Line 146  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEStatementBuilder::VisitNonTerminalParseNode(Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode * in_node) Line 60    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::PSNonTerminalParseNode::AcceptVisitor(Simba::SQLEngine::IParseTreeVisitor & in_visitor) Line 486 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEBuilderBaseT<Simba::SQLEngine::AEStatement,Simba::Support::AutoPtr<Simba::SQLEngine::AEStatement,Simba::Support::AutoPtr_DefaultDeallocator<Simba::SQLEngine::AEStatement> > >::Build(Simba::SQLEngine::PSParseNode * in_node) Line 70 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::AEAetBuilder::Build(Simba::SQLEngine::PSParseNode * in_node, Simba::SQLEngine::DSIExtSqlDataEngine * in_dataEngine) Line 22  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::SQLEngine::DSIExtSqlDataEngine::Prepare(const Simba::Support::simba_wstring & in_sqlStatement) Line 170 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::ODBC::StatementState::InternalPrepare(wchar_t * in_sqlText, int in_textLength, bool in_isDirectExecute) Line 1492   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::ODBC::StatementState::DoPrepare(wchar_t * in_sqlText, int in_textLength, bool in_isDirectExecute) Line 877  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::ODBC::StatementState::SQLPrepareW(wchar_t * StatementText, long TextLength) Line 742    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::ODBC::StatementState1::SQLPrepareW(wchar_t * StatementText, long TextLength) Line 43    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::ODBC::Statement::SQLPrepareW(wchar_t * StatementText, long TextLength) Line 1253    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!Simba::ODBC::SQLPrepareTask<1>::DoSynchronously(Simba::ODBC::Statement & in_stmt, const Simba::ODBC::SQLPrepareTask<1>::TaskParameters & in_params) Line 211   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!DoTask<Simba::ODBC::SQLPrepareTask<1> >(const char * in_functionName, void * in_handle, Simba::ODBC::SQLPrepareTask<1>::TaskParameters & in_parameters) Line 685   C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!SQLPrepareW::__l3::<lambda>() Line 4061    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!std::_Callable_obj<short <lambda>(void),0>::_ApplyX<short>() Line 284  C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!std::_Func_impl<std::_Callable_obj<short <lambda>(void),0>,std::allocator<std::_Func_class<short> >,short>::_Do_call() Line 229    C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!std::_Func_class<short>::operator()() Line 316 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!_default_sen_odbc_api_function_wrapper_(std::function<short __cdecl(void)> & apiFunction) Line 773 C++
    RDFODBC_sb64.dll!SQLPrepareW(void * StatementHandle, wchar_t * StatementText, long TextLength) Line 4061    C++
    MPAPlugin.dll!SQLPrepareW(void * StatementHandle, wchar_t * StatementText, long TextLength) Line 2251   C++
    odbc32.dll!SQLPrepareCover()    Unknown
    odbc32.dll!SQLPrepare()    Unknown
    sasodb.dll!00000000064a7ab9()   Unknown
    sasodb.dll!0000000006493e06()   Unknown
    sasioodb.dll!00000000063917a4() Unknown
    sasxdbi.dll!000000000641e0fa()  Unknown
    sasxdbi.dll!00000000063e5abb()  Unknown
    sasyoio.dll!000000000a22ad5f()  Unknown
    sasyoio.dll!000000000a227597()  Unknown
    sassqlp.dll!000000000a18a787()  Unknown
    sassqlp.dll!000000000a189d8e()  Unknown
    sassqlp.dll!000000000a176853()  Unknown
    sassqlp.dll!000000000a170cd2()  Unknown
    sassqx.dll!0000000009fd54b3()   Unknown
    sassqx.dll!0000000009fd4c0e()   Unknown
    sassql.dll!0000000009f8147c()   Unknown
    sashost.dll!000000000376a366()  Unknown
    sashost.dll!0000000003770574()  Unknown
    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart() Unknown
```

They're using the driver with SAS, and in both stack traces, it looks like it's going to call into ICU (we build it ourselves and add the 'sb' prefix), but instead it somehow (through those 4 frames of garbage [I'm assuming the debugger isn't correctly unwinding the stack???]) calls back into SAS?

I would think that the stack is just corrupted or something, but in the first one, the crash is caused by an assertion that the given statement isn't currently being used (an assertion which should never fail), but, looking in the debugger, it's the same handle being passed into odbc32.dll!SQLPrepareCover() 'below' as into odbc32.dll!FreeStmt() 'above', so it makes sense that the assertion would fail, as we'd be able to lock our mutexes again (they're recursive) and re-enter where it shouldn't have been possible.

I can't think of anything that would cause this, other than maybe SAS using fibers, or some other sort of green threads? Or a signal handler? (but I thought that worked differently on windows, and I would think it would show up on the stack). Is some function pointer table for ICU being corrupted to point into SAS somehow? ICU & SAS should know nothing about each other.

Comment: `cccccccccccccccc()  Unknown` looks suspicious to me.  Maybe that is where things go haywire?   If that is a VS runtime pointer, that (I believe) means "uninitialized stack memory".  Also, note it seems that `operator->` is part of both dumps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot about this question.

The issue ended up being caused by an seh handler that sas installed, which got triggered because sas enabled floating point exceptions, and then called into the driver. ICU didn't expect fp exceptions to be enabled, triggered one, and then the sas cleanup crashed the process